# Jar file runs forever when executed via excel vba

Tags: java, excel, vba, cmd

I have a macro enabled Excel. one of the macros executes a jar file. The jar file downloads file from a site and put it in my documents.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Const WshRunning = 0
Const WshFinished = 1
Const WshFailed = 2
Dim i As Integer

strCommand = "javaw -jar " & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\\somejar.jar " 

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshShellExec = WshShell.exec(strCommand)

i = 0
Do While WshShellExec.Status = WshRunning
    Sleep 5000
     Application.StatusBar = "Downloading " & i
    'MsgBox ("Running")
    i = i + 1
Loop

Select Case WshShellExec.Status
  Case WshFinished
      strOutput = WshShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll()
      Application.StatusBar = "Download Completed!"
 Case WshFailed
     strOutput = WshShellExec.StdErr.ReadAll()
     Application.StatusBar = "Download failed"
 End Select
```

The code works pretty well in my system @ home. It downloads the data fast.

But when I try in the system @ office, it keeps printing 'Downloading 1'.. 'Downloading 40' and goes on. It  is printing forever. Looks like the status is always 0 (WshRunning)

And it goes to not responding when I switch programs or click somewhere. But if I run the java -jar command from the cmd window, it executes and downloads the file

I have set up the java_home, path variable in both the system. In home I have something like "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java.. " In office I have pointed it to "C:\Program Files\Java.." Hope it is 32 and 64 bit. WIll that affect the program ?

Home system has windows 10. Office system is a mac and I launch windows 10 with parallels.

Both in office and home, Am running the excel from dropbox sync folder

Am trying to understand what settings I should change in office desktop to make it work ?

Thanks!

Valli

Comment: what exactly are you asking us about? the running of the jar file? in that case, we're missing the information about said jar file

Comment: If your code runs but is just slow, then this question may be better suited to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Does your workbook path have spaces? If yes then you should be quoting it. Why the double \\ in your path?

Comment: Did you try to run the script manually at office?

Comment: @stultuske the jar file downloads finance information as a csv file from yahoo site. I do not have the code. And I picked the jar file from yahoo site.

Comment: @ashleedawg am not sure if it's an code issue. Because it runs pretty fast at home system. It doesn't run at all in office. So am wondering if it is a network issue or configuration issue

Comment: #Tim Williams there is no space in my path. And the // will become / while running

Comment: @Vincent G yes I did try running manually @ office via cmd window. And it was fast and it returned the results